# Determinant of triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I understand that you can find the determinant of a matrix along its diagonal if it is in triangular form. For a matrix such as the following

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 5 & 0\\ 
2 & 4 & -1\\
0 &-2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

When put into triangular form, I get

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 5 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1/6\\
0 & 0 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Since I multiplied row two by $-\frac16$ during the row reduction, I would expect the determinant to be

$$ 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac13 \cdot \left(-\frac16\right),$$

but the answer for the determinant of the original matrix is $-2$. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Write your row operations as a matrix product and use the multiplication rule for determinants. Then you will minimize your risk of mistakes.

Comment: You should multiply by $-6$ rather than $-1/6$

Comment: @mathreadler I understand the multiplication rule, but was just wondering why this scenario did not work when trying to solve using a triangular matrix

Comment: it will work if you do it right. there is a larger chance you will do it right if you write it down step by step with matrix products

Comment: @eepperly16 I multiplied by -1/6 because during the row operation, row 2 I multiplied by -1/6 to make the 6 a 1 in that row.

Comment: So if you multiplied the second row by $-1/6$ while row reducing, the determinant of the triangular matrix will be $(-1/6)$th of the determinant of the original matrix so to get the determinant of the original matrix you must...

Answer (score 3):

You can add a multiple of any row to another row without changing the determinant. So I'll do these kinds of operations to get to the triangular form.

Start with

$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 5 & 0 \\ 2 & 4 & -1 \\ 0 &-2 &0 \end{matrix}$$

Subtract twice the first row from the second:

$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & -6 & -1 \\ 0 &-2 &0 \end{matrix}$$

Subtract one-third the new second row from the third:

$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & -6 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \end{matrix}$$

The product along the diagonal is $-2$.

Pulling out a factor from one of the rows, however, does change the determinant by that factor. You pulled out $-1/6$ from the second row, so the calculated determinant from the diagonal in your question statement was low by this factor.

Comment: This really does not help with the understanding as you have not shown that the operations you perform don't change the determinant.

Comment: @mathreadler Added a couple of sentences at the beginning to address your concern.

Comment: @mathreadler Was there a problem with my approach to putting it in triangular form? I took the approach of how I would usually go about putting a matrix into reduced echelon form. Is there some property that I may be missing?

Comment: The matrix you ended up with is the same as mine, except your second row is multiplied by $-1/6$. "Pulling out" that constant changes the determinant by the same factor: $-2 \times -1/6 = 1/3$, which was what you got.

Comment: You need to keep track of how the operations you apply may change the determinant.

Comment: @mathreadler Are you addressing that to me, or to Pulse? I know that.

Comment: Obviously to Pulse as he is asking the question. Even if you know that you don't bother to explain it particularly well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realized I should have taken the inverse factor and multiplied it by the determinant.